# I can't connect 8161/admin when activeMQ replicated levelDB with zookeeper

Tags: activemq-classic

If I configured activemq.xml as follows, i can't connect  123.57.167.211:8161. why ?

```
    replicatedLevelDB directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb" 
    replicas="3" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0"
    zkAddress="10.172.5.40:2181,10.170.253.39:2181,10.165.112.136:2181"
    zkPassword="password"  
    zkPath="/activemq40/leveldb-stores"  
    sync="local_disk"
    hostname="123.57.167.211"
```

Answer (score 0):

when replicas="3", you need to start at least 2 activemqs for the cluster to run.
One of them will be the master, you can connect only  to the master's 8161, as only the master is actually running.